# Cloud Storage python client fails to retrieve bucket

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am trying to use the python client library to write blobs to cloud storage. The VM I'm using has Read/Write permissions for storage and I'm able to access the bucket via gsutil, however python is giving me the following error

```
>>> from google.cloud import storage
>>> storage_client = storage.Client()
>>> bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("gs://<bucket name>")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 225, in get_bucket
bucket.reload(client=self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/_helpers.py", line 108, in reload
_target_object=self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/gs://<bucket name>?projection=noAcl: Not Found
```

Comment: The url in the error is `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/gs://<bucket name>`.... you probably just need to supply the _actual_ bucket name (without `gs://`.

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Phix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978005/phix) is right. You only need to specify the bucket name without the 'gs://'. As a matter of fact the API being called (e.g. Buckets: update https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket) is found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets). And here is more on Python's [Google Cloud Storage API client library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) and an [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) of how to use it.