# Vertex AI Pipelines: APIs from v1 namespace not supported in v2 compiler

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I started taking [my first steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973994/16706763) in Vertex AI on past week. As you can see, that basic code works, however it displays the following warning:

```
/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kfp/v2/compiler/compiler.py:1266: FutureWarning: APIs imported from the v1 namespace (e.g. kfp.dsl, kfp.components, etc) will not be supported by the v2 compiler since v2.0.0
  category=FutureWarning,
```

Plus, if I run the same pipeline again, "the warning disappears". What am I missing in my code, which could make that warning disappear at all times (i.e., solve it)?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that warning won't be going anywhere since there are [plans on kfp migrating to version 2](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/7238).  It might be possible to make the warning disappear if v2 of kfp is used upon release?  You can also create a [github issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues) to ask if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: I see. So "kpf.v2" will eventualy become "kpf" again, and (implicitely) the shown warning will (probably) disappear, right?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm also assuming. But the final say will come from the kfp team.

Comment: As discussed in the comments there was not much to do about it till kfp2 were released > It seems that warning won't be going anywhere since there are plans on kfp migrating to version 2. It might be possible to make the warning disappear if v2 of kfp is used upon release?